# Usb show incorrect size

Tags: disk

i installed Ubuntu os on my 32gb usb stick, but when i boot up it show the size only 26gb not 32gb, i dont want to format and install again. any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To show the disk spaces and sizes of all disk**
================================================= Use Ubuntu Live USB:

**There are commands to do this :**

## Terminal :

**Some examples :**

1. **lislblockdevices:**
2. **parted:**

   ```
   sudo parted -l
   ```
3. **fdisk:**

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

Comment: hi, i see there is a new disk called lvm, about 3.9gb "ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]". I think i accidentally clicked lvm when installing ubuntu os. is this fine should i just leave it there?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: Edited my post. Fixed.